# Eclipselink - Onetomany - Poor performance

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, one-to-many, many-to-one

I am going to try to explain clearly my problem.

**Context**: I am doing a web app with : glassfish v3, EclipseLink. My problem is about the low performances of a bidirectionnal oneToMany relationship.

I have one class Event and one class photo. One Event can have one or more photos, and reciprocally, one can belong to 0 or only one event.

**Before**: I did mapping by myself. So when I needed to load all Photo objects for a given Event, I simply used a query : select * from Photo p where p.event_id_fk = SOMETHING. It gave me for one query all needed Photo objects.

Now: I used JPA annotation @OneToMany as follow :

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "photo" )
public class Photo{

@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
@Column( name = "ID" )
private long        idPhoto;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn( name = "EVENT_ID" )
private Event       event;

... other fields ...
```

And

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "event" )
public class Event {

@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
@Column( name = "ID" )
private Long        idEvent;


@OneToMany( mappedBy = "event", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
private List<Photo> photos = new ArrayList<Photo>();

... other fiels ...
```

The problem is that when I select the List photos from Event object (just doing event.getPhotos() ), I can read the JPA generated query :

```
Précis: SELECT ...ALL FIELDS... FROM photo_account WHERE (PHOTO_ID =     ?)
bind => [996]
Précis: SELECT ...ALL FIELDS... FROM photo_account WHERE (PHOTO_ID =     ?)
bind => [997]
Précis: SELECT ...ALL FIELDS... FROM photo_account WHERE (PHOTO_ID =     ?)
bind => [998]
Précis: SELECT ...ALL FIELDS... FROM photo_account WHERE (PHOTO_ID =     ?)
bind => [999]
(...)
```

The result is one query for one photo. In practice, this selection is pretty slow.

Therefore, I would like to know if it exists a way to load all objects by only one query? (custom query, parameters to configure...)
  and/or a best way to map/design the relationship between these objects?
  and more generally if I am doing something bad?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Photo_account isn't mentioned in your listed entities, and you do not show a select to the Photo table.  These problem queries do not seem related to a OneToMany relationship that you've shown, instead they look to be the result of building each instance of Photo due to something you've mapped and not shown, such as an eager OneToOne.  You might look into EclipseLink's joinfetch annotation